# Need to read the previous node's child values to format the current node's value using xsl?

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, loops, xmlnode

I need to use the formats tag while displaying the contents of rowdata, in the  rowdata tags.

the xml is follows: "temp.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Temp.xsl"?>
<ALL_DATA>
    <TITLES>
        <VALUE1>Title1</VALUE1>
        <VALUE2>Title2</VALUE2>
        <FVALUE1>Title3</FVALUE1>
    </TITLES>
    <FORMATS>
        <VALUE1>I5</VALUE1>
        <VALUE2>I3</VALUE2>
        <FVALUE1>F1.1</FVALUE1>
    </FORMATS>
    <MY_DATA>
        <ROWDATA>
            <VALUE1>5</VALUE1>
            <VALUE2>33</VALUE2>
            <FVALUE1>2.11</FVALUE1>
        </ROWDATA>
        <ROWDATA>
            <VALUE1>34</VALUE1>
            <VALUE2>12</VALUE2>
            <FVALUE1>239.81</FVALUE1>
        </ROWDATA>
    </MY_DATA>
</ALL_DATA>
```

and i tried xsl is: "temp.xsl"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:template name="MY_TEMPLATE" match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <TR border="1">
            <xsl:for-each select="/ALL_DATA/TITLES/*">
              <th border="1">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </TR>
          <xsl:for-each select="/ALL_DATA/MY_DATA/ROWDATA">
            <TR>
              <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <TD width ="130">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>:-:
                  <xsl:variable name="cur_node_name" select="name(.)"/>
                  <xsl:for-each select="/ALL_DATA/FORMATS[name(.)]">
                   <!--<xsl:template match="$cur_node_name"> -->
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                   <!--</xsl:template>-->
                </xsl:for-each>
                </TD>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </TR>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am sorry to post entire content.
I feel i can get some help. In above xml, i want to use formats/value1 while displaying the Mydata/rowdata/value1. 
The above Xsl iterates the titles block and display the titles in `<th>`. and then the second for-each block will iterates through rowdata, and its child items.
In displaying child items, i need to use formats tags to display rowdata's childs.

The above xsl is giving output for 3rd tag FValue1 as : `"2.11:-: I5 I3 F1.1"` ; But my expectation is : `"2.11:-: F1.1"`. If i get this solution, i can do the rest. I know just by modifying inner for loop, that can be possible. but could not get that

Please help if any one have suggestion how to.
thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to show your expected output as that would help a lot? Also, in your XSLT, there is a reference to a FORMATS elements, which is not in your input sample. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies! I see it now...

Comment: @all. and the expected output would be like, MyData/Rowdata/FValue1 will be formatted with Fx.1 means. the output table will contains all the row's 3rd value will have only one decimal value output. like i will have to extend till 9 decimal values. If i know for one, i can do for other formats. Thanks for your comments and support.

Comment: The above xsl is giving output for 3rd tag FValue1 as : "2.11:-: I5 I3 F1.1" ;    But my expectation is : "2.11:-: F1.1". If i get this solution, i can do the rest. I know just by modifying inner for loop, that can be possible. but could not get that. Hope this comment will give more understanding.

Comment: Can you amend the original question with the expected output, rather than put it in the comments, because it is much easier to read that way. Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide the exact wanted output and explain the rules for the transformation.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, Thanks for looking into my problem. I just want the output as "2.11:-: F1.1", for the above xsl. Currently it is giving "2.11:-: I5 I3 F1.1". Remaining part i wrote in my code base. If i pass the "F1.1" as arguement(as hard codevalue) it is working fine. Pls help if possible for this.

Comment: @_Haranadh Gupta: Yes, but it isn't clear what are the rules for producing the output from the input. You need to define these precisely, otherwise people will (at best) be guessing, as I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sample data isn't oversimplified your xslt could drop the `for-each` altogether and look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="TITLES" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TITLES">
        <tr>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="./VALUE1" /></th>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="./VALUE2" /></th>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="./FVALUE1" /></th>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROWDATA">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="./VALUE1" />:-:<xsl:value-of select="//FORMATS/VALUE1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="./VALUE2" />:-:<xsl:value-of select="//FORMATS/VALUE2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="./FVALUE1" />:-:<xsl:value-of select="//FORMATS/FVALUE1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MY_DATA">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```